# JS / HTML / CSS navbar for phone size / unable to click for page titles to show

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, javascript-objects

I want to make a dropdown with the different website pages on when max-width of 960px is reached, I have made the button, added the styles, also the JS I have linked it to the HTML ( src="app.js" "in the body tag)

Please see the JS code used for the interactive bar

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhyHI.png)

[CSS CODE - toggle bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwMfk.png)

So below is the whole CSS code, if you require anything more do let me know, everything else is there including the HTML and the JAVA, this is all I've done so far so I am not sure where I have gone wrong

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lato" sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}


.navbar__container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;


}

#navbar__logo{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    background-image: white;
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-gem {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 100%;
}


.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(30, 255, 0) 20%, rgb(5, 0, 0) 100%);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: rgb(0, 255, 13);
    transition: all 0.3 ease;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        background: black;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1000px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 50vh;
        z-index: -1;
        
    }

    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: black;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 50vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
    
    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: white;
    }
    
    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table-column;

    }
    
    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }
    
    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;

    }
    
    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: It is literally not working :((((( every time I press on it it just doesn't work I've got no idea why or how to make it work, any idea whatsoever?

Comment: In that case it's better to post the full code (for the menu) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I have added the CSS full code so whoever looks can see the whole thing!